# Status of ManualValidation for conditions in tasks that follow

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have added a task into some builds that perform a npm audit for vulnerabilities. When any vulnerabilities marked HIGH or SEVERE are found the build errors and vulnerabilities need to be fixed.

The issue is we are now coming up against vulnerabilities that have no fixes available. So I would like to introduce a ManualValidation task when vulnerabilities are found that allows a manager to accept the vulnerabilities and allow the build to complete.

I am trying to use the yaml below. The ManualValidation triggers properly, but when I choose Resume on the manual validation task, the "completeBuildAfterFailedAudit" doesnt run as it sees the validation task as failed().

```
jobs:
  - job: npmAudit
    displayName: Audit dependencies
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines'

    steps:
    - script: |
        npm audit --audit-level=high
      displayName: 'Check for vulnerabilities marked HIGH or SEVERE.'

  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: npmAudit
    condition: failed()
    displayName: Wait for Validation if required
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'

  - job: completeBuildAfterSucessAudit
    displayName: Build after successful audit
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
    dependsOn: npmAudit
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
    - # BUILD STEPS GO HERE

  - job: completeBuildAfterFailedAudit
    displayName: Build after manual audit validation
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
    dependsOn: waitForValidation
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
    - # BUILD STEPS GO HERE
```

What condition can I check for from the manual validation task that will allow the completeBuildAfterFailedAudit job to run?

Or maybe is there a better way to handle this situation that doesn't require the duplication of the build job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If completeBuildAfterSucessAudit and completeBuildAfterFailedAudit are exactly the same job you can completely review your condition and end up triggering the validation only if the npmAudit failed, and letting the build job run if the npmAudit succeed or if the waitForValidation succeed. Your yaml should be similar to this:

```
  jobs:
  - job: npmAudit
    displayName: Audit dependencies
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
        instructions: 'Just testing the success or fail'
        onTimeout: 'reject'

  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: npmAudit
    condition: failed()
    displayName: Wait for Validation if required
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'

  - job: completeBuild
    displayName: Build
    dependsOn: 
    - npmAudit
    - waitForValidation
    condition: or(eq(dependencies.npmAudit.result,'Succeeded'),eq(dependencies.waitForValidation.result,'Succeeded'))
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello World
```

As a side note:

```
condition: succeeded()
```

Means the condition is satisfied only when all previous dependencies with the same agent pool have succeeded. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

As already stated if you want to keep the 2 build jobs separated, you need to set the condition on the success or fail of the specific task, like

```
condition: eq(dependencies.waitForValidation.result,'Succeeded')
```

or

```
condition: eq(dependencies.npmAudit.result,'Succeeded')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did something very similar in my answer below. I didnt know we could logical OR and AND operators in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> What condition can I check for from the manual validation task that
> will allow the completeBuildAfterFailedAudit job to run?

In your scenario, the condition should be "`condition: failed()`" in `completeBuildAfterFailedAudit` job:

```
 - job: completeBuildAfterFailedAudit
    displayName: Build after manual audit validation
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
    dependsOn: waitForValidation
    condition: failed()
    steps:
    - # BUILD STEPS GO HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your situation.

The YAML on your side is not correct, use this:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
#1
- job: npmAudit
  displayName: Audit dependencies
  pool: server

  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # task times out in 1 day
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: 'xxx@xxx.com'
      instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
#2
- job: waitForValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation
  dependsOn: npmAudit
  condition: eq(dependencies.npmAudit.result,'failed')
  pool: server
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # task times out in 1 day
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: 'xxx@xxx.com'
      instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
#3
- job: completeBuildAfterSucessAudit
  displayName: Build after successful audit
  pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
  dependsOn: npmAudit
  condition: eq(dependencies.npmAudit.result,'Succeeded')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.

        Write-Host "Hello World"
#4        
- job: completeBuildAfterFailedAudit
  displayName: Build after manual audit validation
  pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
  dependsOn: waitForValidation
  condition: eq(dependencies.waitForValidation.result,'Succeeded')
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.

        Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a big more on the syntax I realized I was able to use multiple conditions. I didnt have to duplicate the build steps. Below is the YAML I used. The build steps will check if the npmAudit job either succeeded (validation step was resumed) or skipped (npmAudit task didnt fail).

```
jobs:
  - job: npmAudit
    displayName: Audit dependencies
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines'

    steps:
    - script: |
        npm audit --audit-level=high
      continueOnError: true
      displayName: 'Check for vulnerabilities marked HIGH or SEVERE.'

  - job: waitForValidation
    dependsOn: npmAudit
    condition: eq(dependencies.npmAudit.result, 'SucceededWithIssues')
    displayName: Wait for Validation if required
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'reject'

  - job: completeBuildAfterSucessAudit
    displayName: Build after successful audit
    pool: 'Azure Pipelines' 
    dependsOn: npmAudit
    condition: |
      in(dependencies.waitForValidation.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
    steps:
    - # BUILD STEPS GO HERE
```